# Iterating through an instance of a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is the code I'm working with.

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as csvfile:
    mpg = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    print(mpg)
```

Output:

```
<csv.DictReader object at 0x7f6661fa8780>
```

The above code gives me a DictReader instance 
'mpg'.

Now, the below code is where I get confused.

```
with open('sample.csv') as csvfile:
    mpg = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in mpg:
        print(row)
```

Here, I'm getting each row as OrderedDict. But, my question is how can I loop through an instance 'mpg' of DictReader, it is at the end an object, not a list or something like that?

Please help me to get the concept.

Comment: It is an object. So is "a list or something like that". A string is an object, a number is too, practically everything is an object in Python.

Comment: `print` just gives you the string representation of the object itself.  `mpg` is a `DictReader` object.  When you `print` the object it shows you the object's `__str__` implementation.  When you *iterate* through the object `mpg` it executes the object's `__iter__` implementation, and in this case, it shows you each `row` object inside the `mpg`.  When you `print(row)`, it shows you the string implementation of `row` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Classes can define how they are iterated over by defining an `__iter__()` method; this should take no additional arguments and return a valid iterator object. A class that wants to be an iterator should implement two methods: a `next()` method that behaves as described above, and an `__iter__()` method that returns self.

[PEP 234 -- Iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/#id4)

`DictReader` implements both `__iter__()` and `__next__()`. Therefore, it's both iterable and can be used as an iterator. In fact, `__iter__()` returns itself, which is perfectly fine, as it can be used as an iterator because of `__next__()`. See cpython's implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fce5ff1e18b522cf52379934a6560583d840e7f9/Lib/csv.py#L80). Note that in python 3, `__next__()` was renamed to `next()` ([PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/)).

Comment: I got it...and btw next() was renamed to __next__() in python 3,, this is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This change was proposed in PEP 3114 and got implemented in python 3.0.